# The Basic Fraenkel Model

Tags: set-theory

I was working through Lemma 9.3 in Jech's Axiom of Choice (on page 136).
[image]

Here $V_2$ is the basic Fraenkel model determined by the group of all permutation of the set of atoms and the finite-subset ideal. I didn't understand the reasoing starting from "Since $x \subseteq \pi x$". Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with $x\subseteq\pi x$ and apply $\pi$ to both sides: $\pi x\subseteq\pi^2x$, so $x\subseteq\pi x\subseteq\pi^2x$. By an easy induction $x\subseteq\pi^ix$ for each $i\in\omega$. In particular, if we can find $k$ and $\rho$ as described, we’ll have

$$x\subseteq\pi^kx=\rho x\,.$$

Applying $\rho^{-1}$ to both ends, we see that $\rho^{-1}x\subseteq x$. But $\rho^{-1}x=\rho x$, so

$$x\subseteq\pi^kx=\rho x=\rho^{-1}x\subseteq x\,,$$

and it follows that $x=\pi^kx$. If $x$ were a proper subset of $\pi x$, we’d also have $x\subsetneqq\pi^ix$ for each $i>0$, so we must have $x=\pi x$.

I have no idea, however, how he goes on to find $k$ and $\rho$.